# why is my code going out of bounds?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, quicksort

I wrote this code:

```
class test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;


    method.dog(i, b, c, array);
}
}

public class method {

static void dog (int i, int b, int c,  int array[]) {

    if (array[i] <= array[c]) {
           if (c == (int) array.length +1 ) {
                int y = array[i];
                array[i] = array[b];
                array[b] =  y;
                if (b == array.length +1) return;
                else  b++; i =b; c=b; dog( i, b, c, array);
           }
            else c++; dog( i, b, c, array);
        }else i ++; c= b; dog( i, b, c, array);
    }
}
```

I keep getting the same issue over and over. It keeps saying that I am going out of bounds. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Profanity removed. Come on, there's no need for that.

Comment: Try printing the values of your array so that you can isolate where it is happening.  You're probably trying to use an index that doesn't exist in the array

Comment: Oh please, for the love of debugging and readability, use braces around your if-else statements. I think you may be getting bit by the "one line if-else" stuff.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How to understand your own code: 1. fix the formatting. 2. Use meaningful variable names longer than one character. 3. Use braces. 4. Add System.out.println() statements to print out the values of variables while the code is looping to see where what you think is happening differs from reality. 5. stop blaming it on the tools. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your error see below code.

```
static void dog(int i, int b, int c, int array[]) {

    if (c<array.length-1 && array[i] <= array[c] ) {
        if (c <(int) array.length-1) {
            int y = array[i];
            array[i] = array[b];
            array[b] = y;
            if (b < array.length)
                return;
            else
                b++;
            i = b;
            c = b;
            dog(i, b, c, array);
        } else
            c++;
        dog(i, b, c, array);
    } else
        i++;
    c = b;
    dog(i, b, c, array);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious what it tries to achieve: Dog.

Answer (score 10):

You do know that array indexes go from zero to the size of the array minus one (i.e. they are zero-based)? So valid indexes are `0` to `array.length - 1` (inclusive), so your check `b == array.length +1` is wrong as it allows to high indexes.

Also, those `else` parts only contain a single little statement, not the rest of the statements on the same line.